# Recurse to directory-level only using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to recurse to the last directory level only?

I'm trying to execute the below script:

```
$sourcepath = "\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\target";
$inputdate = '2014-06-02';
$sourcepath
#Get-ChildItem -path $sourcepath
Get-Date;
Get-ChildItem -path $sourcepath -recurse | where-object {$_.fullname.contains("XX") -and $_.fullname.contains($inputdate)} |
foreach-object {
    $_.fullname;
}
Get-Date;
```

---

The above source directory, \xx.xxx.xx.xx\ftpcopy, has a lot of folders like XX, X1, X2, etc. Inside each of the sub folders there are folders like '2014-06-01', '2014-06-02', etc.

Inside each of these subfolders there are files. There are a total of 68 of these sub folders and all of them contains files. My goal is to use the script to just list the names of the files inside the folder, \xx.xxx.xx.xxx\ftpcopy\XX\2014-06-02.

Later I want to generalize so that it lists the names of files under folder '2014-06-02' under any subfolder 'XX','X1','X2', etc. when I pass the parameters 'sourcepath' and 'inputdate'.

When I execute this script it takes 45 minutes to execute which is very long. I'm thinking this is due to the many files inside each sub folder; it has to recurse through all of those as well to find the matching pattern.

If there is a way to recurse only to the last folder level like for example '2014-06-02' then it could make the script run faster. xx.xxx.xx.xxx is a remote server which I'm trying to access. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is to try getting a folder only listing, and maybe filtering for $inputdate (I don't trust the file system provider's filtering capability, so I would filter after), then maybe just running a GCI on those folders.

So, something along the lines of:

```
$sourcepath = "\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\ftpcopy"
$inputdate = '2014-06-02'
get-childitem -path $sourcepath -recurse -directory|?{$_.Name -match $inputdate -and $_.fullname.contains("XX")}| %{ GCI $_.fullname }
```

If this is something you want to be able to feed XX and a date to maybe a function would suit you better.

```
Function Get-FTPFiles{
Param(
    $InputDate = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'),
    $sourcepath = "\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\ftpcopy",
    $XX = '.'
)
    get-childitem -path $sourcepath -recurse -directory|?{$_.Name -match $inputdate -and $_.fullname -match "$XX"}| %{ GCI $_.fullname }
}
```

Then you can just call it with no arguments to get all files in any folder with the current day's date, or specify Date, XX Folder, and/or server path.

```
Get-FTPFolders
```

or

```
Get-FTPFolders -InputDate "2014-06-24" -XX "X3"
```

Comment: Thanks for the above. i tried the above but i'm getting the following error: Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'directory'.

Comment: Ah, ok, you have an older version of PowerShell. I would suggest swapping out the line mjolinor suggests then, since you are using an older version of powershell.

Comment: Thanks. i'm using the swapping suggested by mjolinor and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd trade this:

```
get-childitem -path $sourcepath -recurse -directory|?{$_.Name -match $inputdate -and $_.fullname.contains("XX")}| %{ GCI $_.fullname }
```

for

```
(cmd /c dir $sourcepath /b /s /ad) -match $inputdate -match '\\xx\\' | GCI
```

Edit:

Comment: when i execute the above nothing happens. there is no output on screen.

Comment: If you run just this much: (cmd /c dir $sourcepath /b /s /ad) do you get a directory list?

Comment: yes, it is listing the directories when i run only the above mentioned line of script. it took about 5 mts to run

Comment: If it's returning the directory strings, and any of them match both $Inputdate and have \xx\ in their path it should return those.  5 minutes to run seems extremely excessive.  How many directories are in that folder structure?

Comment: under xx.xxx.xx.xxx/ftpcopy there are 53 folders. then inside each of those 53 folders there are about 60-70 folders. then each of the 60-70 folders have files (could be anything between 1 to 100 files in each)

Comment: 5 minutes still seems excessive, and it should be finding the matching directories, but I don't have enough information to debug that any further.

Comment: Thanks. now when i put the match for inputdate and \xx\ i get the desired result directory for fetching the files from. it still takes 5 mts to do the directory listing and the match as well.

Comment: Still seems like a long time, but that may be your network. Sounds better than the 45 minutes it took before, though.